# make sigma.js compatible with ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, graph-visualization, sigma.js

Please help me,this drives me nuts.

I have a ruby on rails application , the following code is from sigma.js example to visualize graph files.I do not know why the graph does not render

some notes:

1.java script files sigma.min and parseGexf are located correctly,looking at source code of the browser I can see them

2.the data file "file.gexf" is the problem I think .I do not know what else to try the following helpers did not work

```
asset_path

asset_url
```

I also tried to pass the absolute path of the file.gexf still did not work

```
<% content_for :header do %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag "sigma.min", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "sigma.parseGexf", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<% end %>

  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="sigma-parent" id="sigma-example-parent">
      <div class="sigma-expand" id="sigma-example"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
  // Instanciate sigma.js and customize rendering :
  var sigInst = sigma.init(document.getElementById('sigma-example')).drawingProperties({
   ...
    defaultEdgeType: 'curve'
   }).graphProperties({
   ...
  }).mouseProperties({
    maxRatio: 32
  });

  // Parse a GEXF encoded file to fill the graph
 // (requires "sigma.parseGexf.js" to be included)
 sigInst.parseGexf('file.gexf');
 //highlights the nodes that is hovered+ its edges
 // Bind events :
 var greyColor = '#666';
 sigInst.bind('overnodes',function(event){
    ...
    // Draw the graph :
    sigInst.draw(); 
 }

 if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
 } else {
   window.onload = init;
}
   </script>
//some stylinmg here 

   <style type="text/css">
       .sigma-parent {
    position: relative;
   ...
  }
   .sigma-expand {
     position: absolute;
  ...
  }
  .buttons-container{
     padding-bottom: 8px;
   ...  }
</style>
```

Comment: Have you tried to move the `sigInst.draw();` outside of the sigInst.draw(); overnodes` event listener callback?

Comment: I feel your pain user1876128. Been struggling from the same problem.